# iPad 1 showing portrait mode instead of Landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode4.5

I have an application on AppStore that has portrait Mode on iPhone and on iPad it works on landscape. However i am getting reports that it shows portrait on iPad 1 thus destroyed overall View.

Why is iPad 1 specifically showing Portrait mode?
The version of iPad is 5.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ios 6, the methods for supporting interface orientation has been changed. For supporting both interface orientation in both version, we need to check the os version and write code acoordingly.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); 
}
```

Support for new versions

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   }
```

In my View Controller i have the following:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go and make sure **ALL** view controllers return the correct orientation modes they support. I've seen such behaviour in iOS 5 and if I recall correctly that was the reason.

Comment: I see no problems in any orientations? I have set Landscape and for iphone portrait. What else can be there?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar from and I resolved it by changing the following code in AppDelegate.m-> applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
 [self.window addSubview:self.viewController];
```

to

```
 [self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
```